# Protocol extension default method causing a "self is immutable" error

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I am trying to extend a class-bound protocol (`UITextInputTraits`) with a default method:

```
extension UITextInputTraits where Self: UIView {

    func setTextInputTraits() {

        self.autocapitalizationType = .none // <- compiler error
    }
}
```

It gives a `"Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable"` error.

It works if I change the constraint from `UIView` to `UITextField` though, but that defeats the purpose of using protocols.

Why is it an error? How can I achieve implementing this default method?

Thank you!

---

- cannot mark the func `mutating`, since `'mutating' isn't valid on methods in classes or class-bound protocols`
- tried sending messages to self, Objective-C style, but `perform` does not work with non-object value arguments:

  ```
  func setTextInputTraits() {

      let sel = #selector(setter: self.autocapitalizationType)
      self.perform(sel, with: .none)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works if I change the constraint from UIView to UITextField though, but that defeats the purpose of using protocols. Why is it an error?

Because UIView doesn't already *have* an `autocapitalizationType` property. Thus, the compiler has no reason to believe that if it *did* have one, it would be settable.

> How can I achieve implementing this default method?

I think you might be after something like this:

```
protocol MyTextInputTraits : UITextInputTraits {
    var autocapitalizationType: UITextAutocapitalizationType {get set}
}
extension MyTextInputTraits {
    func setTextInputTraits() {
       self.autocapitalizationType = .none
    }
}
extension UITextView : MyTextInputTraits {}
extension UITextField : MyTextInputTraits {}
extension UISearchBar : MyTextInputTraits {}
```